# Option type compatible with comprehensions in Elixr?

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension, monads

### Background

I am trying to up my Functional Programming (FP) skills and one of the things that newcomers first learn in FP is the `Option` Type (aka, [Maybe Monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/Maybe)).

### Option what?

This construct is present in many languages, Haskell has Maybe and Java  and Python (yes, Python!) have Optional.

Basically this type **models a value that may or may not be there**.

[image]

### How it all comes down to Elixir

Most FP languages have [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#the-into-option), Scala and Elixir have the `for` construct while Haskell has its famous `do` notation.

In Scala and Haskell, these comprehensions work not only with Enumerables (such as Lists) but also with our `Option` type (which is not an enumerable).

I mention this, because according to my understanding, Elixir's comprehensions **only** works on Enumerables. Furthermore, as far as I know, there is not `Option` type datastructure in Elixir.

### What does Elixir have?

Elixir has tagged tuples in the form of `{:ok, val}` or `{:error, reason}`. Now while Elixir comprehensions can pattern match with tagged tuples:

```
iex> values = [good: 1, good: 2, bad: 3, good: 4]
iex> for {:good, n} <- values, do: n * n
[1, 4, 16]
```

It also ignores values that do not pattern match:

```
iex> values = [good: 1, good: 2, bad: 3, good: 4]
iex> for {:bananas, n} <- values, do: n * n
[]
```

However, this does not replicate the behaviour of the `Option` type correctly. Following is an example in Scala:

```scala
  for {
      validName  <- validateName(name)
      validEnd   <- validateEnd(end)
      validStart <- validateStart(start, end)
    } yield Event(validName, validStart, validEnd)
```

Having in mind this signatures:

```
def validateName(name: String): Option[String]
def validateEnd(end: Int): Option[Int]
def validateStart(start: Int, end: Int): Option[Int]
```

The result of the full comprehension expression, should any function return `None` , will be `None`.

With Elixir, the bad result would be ignored and the pipeline would simply continue happily ever after.

### Questions

At this point I am thinking that implement this `Option` type as a structure that implements the `Enumerable` Protocol (so it can be used in Elixir comprehensions) is something that should be possible.

However, I am not sure I want to go down that route if I can simulate similar behavior using tuples.

So I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to simulate the `Option` type using tagged tuples inside Elixir comprehensions?
2. Are there any Elixir libraries in the wild that have Monadic types (like the one we saw here) usable within Elixir comprehensions? (I know about [witchcraft](https://github.com/witchcrafters/witchcraft) but they have their own construct for comprehensions, which for the time being, I think is a little overkill. I am interesting in something that works with Elixir's native comprehension functionality).

Comment: in my experience option types are specially implemented for static typed languages, they convert side effects to data, I never saw the necessity of Option type in elixir. Python most probably adopted this so that they can migrate people to their language easier.

Comment: You can have a decent level of static typing with Elixir as well via Dialyzer (which I would recommend). Nevertheless, my questions still remain unanswered.

Comment: I have nothing against static type analyzers, they are good in some places. What I hate to see is people implementing such logic in production instead of using the official way, such projects do not age well. Javascript and Python are good examples, bloated with functionality, they lost the sight of what these languages were designed for.

Comment: I respect your opinion. Let's leave this friendly exchange of ideas for now.

Comment: I was not familiar with this concept, nor was I aware that Elixir's `for` construct would sort of skip any values which didn't have a match on the left-side of `<-` -- I suppose this is like the `with` statement in that if there isn't a match, flow is redirected (optionally to an `else` block).  

Is this fundamentally different than, say, defining 2 function clauses (one for valid input, one to handle the "none" path)? E.g. `def option(:foo), do: "Yes"` and `def option(_), do: nil`

Comment: @Everett Yes. First because comprehensions in Elixir do not offer an "else" block or path. Second because comprehensions are basically syntatic sugar for `Enum.flat_map`. So while the `with` statement is useful for some specific scenarios (one of them being the one you pointed out with you `def foo` function) comprehensions are in theory more powerful, because they can do anything their generators allow and are not limited to one line executions (like `with` statements, which are executed one line at a time).

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.  I've bookmarked the question in hopes someone can shed light on it.

Comment: I think `with` might still be the more idiomatic way to achieve your validation example, with functions returning `:ok` | `:error` tuples. This great [discussion](https://podcast.thinkingelixir.com/82) (30:08) with Jose Valim about `with` and monads in Elixir might be interesting and covers precisely the differences between `for` and `with`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

After searching for all the functional libraries Elixir has on hex, at the time of this writing none matched my main requirement:

- Being usable with Elixir comprehensions.

Some say Elixir comprehensions are not powerful enough for such cases. This is a falsifiable claim, so I  decided to go ahead and try to falsify it.

### Say Hi to `Option.ex`

Yes, the name is not inspiring. Originality has never been my *forté*.
But what is this?

Simply put, this is an option type for elixir, aka, Option/Maybe monad. Yes, another one.

And just like what most people coming from languages like Scala/Haskell/Python have come to know, it has a couple of subtypes `Some` and `None`.

**option.ex**

```
defmodule Option do
  @type t(elem) :: __MODULE__.Some.t(elem) | __MODULE__.None.t()

  defmodule Some do
    @type t(elem) :: %__MODULE__{val: elem}

    defstruct [:val]

    defimpl Collectable do
      @impl Collectable
      def into(option), do: {option, fn acc, _command -> {:done, acc} end}
    end

    defimpl Enumerable do
      @impl Enumerable
      def count(_some), do: {:ok, 1}

      @impl Enumerable
      def member?(some, element), do: {:ok, some.val == element}

      @impl Enumerable
      def reduce(some, acc, fun)

      def reduce(_some, {:halt, acc}, _fun), do: {:halted, acc}
      def reduce(some, {:suspend, acc}, fun), do: {:suspended, acc, &reduce(some, &1, fun)}
      def reduce([], {:cont, acc}, _fun), do: {:done, acc}

      def reduce(%Option.Some{} = some, {:cont, acc}, fun),
        do: reduce([], fun.(some.val, acc), fun)

      @impl Enumerable
      def slice(_option), do: {:error, __MODULE__}
    end
  end

  defmodule None do
    @type t :: %__MODULE__{}

    defstruct []

    defimpl Collectable do
      @impl Collectable
      def into(option) do
        {option,
         fn
           _acc, {:cont, val} ->
             %Option.Some{val: val}

           acc, :done ->
             acc

           _acc, :halt ->
             :ok
         end}
      end
    end

    defimpl Enumerable do
      @impl Enumerable
      def count(_none), do: {:error, __MODULE__}

      @impl Enumerable
      def member?(_none, _element), do: {:error, __MODULE__}

      @impl Enumerable
      def reduce(none, acc, fun)

      def reduce(_none, {:cont, acc}, _fun), do: {:done, acc}
      def reduce(_none, {:halt, acc}, _fun), do: {:halted, acc}
      def reduce(none, {:suspend, acc}, fun), do: {:suspended, acc, &reduce(none, &1, fun)}

      @impl Enumerable
      def slice(_option), do: {:error, __MODULE__}
    end
  end

  @spec new(any) :: __MODULE__.Some.t(any)
  def new(val), do: %__MODULE__.Some{val: val}

  @spec new :: __MODULE__.None.t()
  def new, do: %__MODULE__.None{}
end
```

This works with Elixir comprehensions, and it makes use of the fact that the Optional type is a Functor. This means its main requirement is being able to be mapped over. By converting an abstract container into specific implementation detail (like lists in Elixir) I was able to make it work.

### How can I use it?

The main purpose of this was to add an Option type to elixir to use with comprehensions. So a comparison to other languages is useful:

**In Scala:**

```scala
def parseShow(rawShow: String): Option[TvShow] = {
  for {
    name <- extractName(rawShow)
    yearStart <- extractYearStart(rawShow)
    yearEnd <- extractYearEnd(rawShow)
  } yield TvShow(name, yearEnd, yearStart)
}
```

**In Elixir:**

```
  @spec parse_show(String.t()) :: Option.t(TvShow.t())
  def parse_show(raw_show) do
    for name <- extract_name(raw_show),
        year_start <- extract_year_start(raw_show),
        year_end <- extract_year_end(raw_show),
        into: Option.new() do
      %TvShow{name: name, year_end: year_end, year_start: year_start}
    end
  end
```

You will see, these two pieces of code are basically identical, with the exception of the line `into: Option.new()`, which is implicit in the Scala example. Elixir requires it to be explicit, which I personally prefer as well.

I could go on with examples from other languages, but they would all read basically the same. This is because comprehensions are basically the same in most FP languages.

But this doesn't answer the full original post ...

### What about an Elixir equivalent in tagged tuples?

You can't use tagged tuples to achieve the same thing using comprehensions. This is impossible.
However, if we discard comprehensions and focus on Elixir's other constructs, we can come a little bit closer.

Quoting another prominent member of Elixir's community, @OvermindDL1 :

> Is it possible to simulate the `Option` type using tagged tuples inside Elixir comprehensions?
>
> Yes, or with `with` if you want an else, but you’ll want to make the tagged typed be `ok: value` and `error: reason` (which is closer to a result type, but it’s a limitation of elixir tuple lists in that they are always tuples). Traditionally `{:ok, value}` and `:error` is the “option” type in Elixir, where `{:ok, value}` and `{:error, reason}` is the “result” type in Elixir.

So, if you are coming from a different setting, from a functional language into Elixir, this post and my `option.ex` is most certainly going to help you.

If however, you'd rather stay away from Mathematical Categories and other functional concepts like you want to stay away from the plague, `with` statements with other elixir's constructs ought to serve you well enough.

One is not better than the other, they have different costs/benefits. It's up to you.